# Solution to simultaneous polynomial equations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given any $\beta \in R$, do there exist integers $k,l,m$, and a real number $x$ such that:

$l=4x^{3}m+6x^{2}m^{2}+4xm^{3}-2xm$,

as well as

$x^{4}-x^{2}=k+\beta$ ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Take $k=-\beta$ and $x=0$, with $l=m=0$.

Comment: $\beta$ is not necessarily an integer, while $k$ is

Comment: @DietrichBurde Doesn't work if $\beta\notin\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first equation, $x$ is algebraic. This implies $\beta$ algebraic, which might not hold.

There are countably many values of $\beta$ that give solutions. We can enumerate them by considering all triples $(k,l,m)$, finding the roots in $x$ and computing $\beta=x^4-x^2-k$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing out that $\beta$ can only be countable. In general, sums and products of algebraic numbers are algebraic, and so we conclude the first statement.